# how to authenticate and use amplify sdk on my backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

This question is both a possible answer, and a question about how to improve this answer.

I've used amplify SDK on my backend to run scripts that interact with my backend directly (execute db migrations scripts, etc).

I've used amplify SDK on my backend because it directly simulates user interactions and handle much of the complexity, for example, when creating a record in a table, the `createdAt`,`upadtedAt`,`id` is automatically defined and GQL validations based on your schema takes place, while using DynamoDB SDK to change the DB does not go through validation and fields are not automatically populated.

So I have 2 questions to you guys:

- My previous method suddenly stopped working and I'm not sure why. can someone help me fix it?
- There is a better way? why I can't find a single tutorial on the internet about how to authenticate and interact with the amplify SDK directly in the backend? why i have to mock the amplify auth flow just to run some scripts to update my db?

  - what is the best practices in the context about updating your amplify DB using scripts running from the backend?

#### My current method

*which no longer works now, not sure why*

- I've created admin user in my Cognito pool with admin privileges, using password as authentication method.
- I've created [custom credentials provider](https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/advanced-workflows/), and overridden the `getCredentials` to grab the credentials from the Cognito pool using aws-sdk for javascript.
- I've hardcoded the username and password when running the script to mock that the amplify operations made by the script is made by this admin user.

```js
// auth.ts
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsConfig from "../../src/aws-exports";
import {
  CredentialsAndIdentityId,
  CredentialsAndIdentityIdProvider,
  GetCredentialsOptions,
  getCurrentUser,
} from "aws-amplify/auth";
import { fromCognitoIdentityPool } from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers";
import {
  AuthenticationDetails,
  CognitoUser,
  CognitoUserPool,
} from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
import type { CognitoIdentityCredentials } from "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-cognito-identity/dist-types/fromCognitoIdentity";

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
  UserPoolId: awsConfig.aws_user_pools_id,
  ClientId: awsConfig.aws_user_pools_web_client_id,
});

const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
  Username: "<your-admin-email>", // replace with the user's username
  Pool: userPool,
});

const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
  Username: "<your-admin-userid>", // replace with the user's id from the user pool
  Password: "<your-admin-password>", // replace with the user's password
});

const getUserIdentityIdPromise = () =>
  new Promise<CognitoIdentityCredentials>((resolve, reject) => {
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: async function (result) {
        const logins = {} as any;
        logins[
          `cognito-idp.${awsConfig.aws_cognito_region}.amazonaws.com/${awsConfig.aws_user_pools_id}`
        ] = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();

        const getCredentials = fromCognitoIdentityPool({
          clientConfig: { region: awsConfig.aws_cognito_region },
          identityPoolId: awsConfig.aws_cognito_identity_pool_id,
          logins: logins,
        }) as () => Promise<CognitoIdentityCredentials>;
        // return resolve(getCredentials);
        const credentials = await getCredentials();

        const identityId = credentials.identityId;

        resolve(credentials);
      },
      onFailure: function (err) {
        console.error(err);
        reject(err);
      },
    });
  });

const userCredentials = await getUserIdentityIdPromise();

class CustomCredentialsProvider implements CredentialsAndIdentityIdProvider {
  async getCredentialsAndIdentityId(
    getCredentialsOptions: GetCredentialsOptions,
  ): Promise<CredentialsAndIdentityId | undefined> {
    try {
      // const credentials = userCredentials
      const credentials: CredentialsAndIdentityId = {
        credentials: userCredentials,
        identityId: userCredentials.identityId,
      };
      return credentials;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error getting credentials: ", e);
    }
  }

  // Implement this to clear any cached credentials and identityId. This can be called when signing out of the federation service.
  clearCredentialsAndIdentityId(): void {}
}

const customCredentialsProvider = new CustomCredentialsProvider();

Amplify.configure(awsConfig, {
  Auth: {
    // Supply the custom credentials provider to Amplify
    credentialsProvider: customCredentialsProvider,
  },
});

console.log("current user", await getCurrentUser()); // now throws error. used to work.
```

now each time I want to authenticate in a script that is making some useful operations i've simply imported the `auth.ts` file in the script:

```js
// list-questions.ts
/**
 * list all questions from the database
 */
import "./auth.ts";
import { generateClient } from "aws-amplify/api";
import { listQuestions } from "../../src/graphql/queries.ts";

const client = generateClient();

const questions = await client.graphql({
  query: listQuestions.replaceAll("__typename", ""),
  variables: {
    limit: 1,
  },
});

console.log(questions);
```

this used to work like charm, and i could easily run script from my backend as if each operation executed by the script was executed by the mock admin user defined in the `auth.ts` file.